# Excel formula less than equal to 10 minute average for column

Tags: average, countif

I have a range of approximately 1800 time increments (HH:MM:SS) in one column, sorted from low to high.

I am trying to come up with a formula that will produce the percentage of cells that are equal to or less than 10 minutes (10:00:00) of the approximately 1800 cells.

I'm not sure if I should be using AVERAGEIFS or another formula.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vagueness in the question. Is the time absolute and you want to compare among them or relative to a specified time. For the first case, you may very well use countif.
To get the cells less than equal to 10minutes:

```
countif(range,"<00:10:01")
```

Based on the comment, you can use this single formula:

```
=(COUNTIF(range,"<00:10:01")*100)/COUNTA(range)
```

The counta function gives you the number of non-blank cells in a range.

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I appreciate the help. I was wondering if there was a way to combine the countif formula with the average formula for a group of cells (example R2..R1200) all in one formula for calulcation? Or must you do it in 2 steps as you suggested?

Comment: Updated my answer for a single formula.

Comment: Thank you Rajat! That's exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.